# two isolated dockers, rails and python, how to call python from rails app

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, docker

I have two docker containers. One is a rails app, another includes a python project. Here is the question. Once clicked a button from rails, how to call the python script.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately the container with the python script will need to be running a program called a server. What a server does is it listens for requests and responds, in this way your ruby container can say "hey, python program, please do something for me". You might see if you can integrate your python script into a web server framework such as flask and therefore enable it to be called by your ruby container.

Comment: Thanks. Following your suggestion, I've construct a simple SOA frame. It works well without dockerizing. And even dockerize python server, local client script works. However, when client script dockerized. It fails to connect. The sever is localhost:50000, docker-compose.yml sets network_mode: "host". It works except for when client been dockerized.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much more about docker to help you. Are there some sort of configuration about opening ports or rules about network access to docker containers?